# How can I plot user input data onto a graph with a line of best fit?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

How can I add a line of best fit for data input by the user?
So far I have made a loop for collecting the data and it's length but I'm not sure how to get it to recognise these values as a string of x and y values, and it needs to be an array to do a least squares plot/best fit.
I'm fairly new to coding so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np

x=[]
y=[]

for i in range(1, 20):
    print('Concentration?')
    x = input()
    print('Absorbance?')
    y = input()
    plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label="Data", markersize=5)
    if i == 3:
        break
    else:
        continue



A = np.vstack([x,np.ones(len(x))]).T
print(A)
#
m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)[0]
plt.plot(x,m*x+c, 'r', label="Fit")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your inputs to the list.  Then in your plot you need to calculate the points for y which I've shown in the list comprehension part.

Alternatively you could just use seaborn regplot which will handle all of this for you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x=[]
y=[]

for i in range(1, 20):
    print('Concentration?')
    x.append(float(input()))
    print('Absorbance?')
    y.append(float(input()))
    plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label="Data", markersize=5)
    if i == 3:
        break
    else:
        continue

A = np.vstack([x,np.ones(len(x))]).T
m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)[0]
plt.plot(x,[m*_+c for _ in x], 'r', label="Fit")
```

[image]

```
sns.regplot(x,y, ci=None)
```

[image]